# Select query took long time to executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following function :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SuiviRupture](@CodeArticle [nvarchar](13),@CodeSite [nvarchar](5) ,@CodeStructure [nvarchar](13))
    RETURNS @calcul TABLE 
    (
        [Code Article]     [nvarchar](13),
         [Code Structure][nvarchar](13) NULL,
          [Code Site][nvarchar](5) NULL,
          CAMOY float,

            QTEMOY float

    )
    AS 
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE
       (
            [datecol]   date,
            [Code Article]     [nvarchar](13),
            [Prix de vente TTC] [nvarchar](15) NULL,

            [Code Site][nvarchar](5) NULL,
            [Code Structure][nvarchar](13) NULL,
            Quantité float ,
            rn int
        );


insert into @Temp
    ([datecol],[Code Article],[Prix de vente TTC],[Code Site],[Code Structure],Quantité,rn)

     select t1.[datecol],t1.[Code Article],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.[Code Site],t1.[Code Structure],t1.Quantité ,rn
          from [Vente] t1
          inner join (select distinct [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site],
          row_number() over(Partition by  [Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site] order by [datecol]desc ) as rn

          from (select distinct  [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site]
               from [Vente] t2
                where promo = 0
                and ([Code Article] is not null) and ([Code Structure] is not null) and ([Prix de Revient] is not null )and  [Code Article]= @CodeArticle and [Code Site]=@CodeSite and [Code Structure]=@CodeStructure
        )g
              ) a
               on a.datecol=t1.datecol
                and t1.[Code Article] = a.[Code Article]
                and t1.[Code Structure]=a.[Code Structure]
                and t1.[Code Site]=a.[Code Site]
                where promo = 0 --and  t1.[Code Article]= '    020130180'  
                and  rn <= 28

       INSERT @calcul 
    select 
          [Code Article]
          ,[Code Structure]
          ,[Code Site]
         , sum(convert(float,Quantité))/count(distinct [datecol])  as QTEMOY
        ,  sum(convert(float,[Prix de vente TTC])) / count(distinct [datecol]) AS CAMOY
    from @Temp
    where   [Code Article]= @CodeArticle and [Code Site]=@CodeSite and [Code Structure]=@CodeStructure
    group by
          [Code Article],[Code Structure]
          ,[Code Site]
     RETURN;
    END;


    GO
```

when I execute the following query , it took too long time , hours to be executed 
How to optimize it ?

```
 select  t1.[Code Article],t1.[Code Site],t1.[Code Structure], u.QTEMOY,u.CAMOY
      from V_distinctVente t1  With(nolock)
      Cross apply dbo.[SuiviRupture](t1.[Code Article],t1.[Code Site],t1.[Code Structure]) u
```

Comment: Try to view the actual execution plan and see if there are any smells.

Comment: You have asked a question that could perhaps refer to a view `V_distinctVente`, but then not provided the definition of that view. Your question is therefore unanswerable unless you provide definitions and indexes

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to replicate without knowing the actual background. You can put this query in sql analyzer and try to make the changes suggested there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using function which is never precompiled like stored procedure .Use Stored Procedure then you may have performance boost up .Store procedure compiles the query and saved result in execution plan in sql server. this link may help [link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/7EDL150912-Difference-between-Stored-Procedure-and-Function-in-SQL-Server.html)